# $X=\mathbb{Z}$,$\mathfrak B:= \{a+b\mathbb{Z}:a \in \mathbb{Z}, b \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a basis of a topology on $X$?

Tags: general-topology

$X=\mathbb{Z}$

$$\mathfrak B:= \{a+b\mathbb{Z}:a \in \mathbb{Z}, b \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

I need to show that $\mathfrak{B}$ is as basis of a topology on $X$, but I have no clue which topology has $\mathfrak{B}$ as a basis.

The hint I received is $a+b \mathbb{Z}=x+b \mathbb{Z} \ \forall x \in a + b \mathbb{Z}$ but that doesn't really help me either.

Answer (score 0):

Another hint:

If you must check whether any collection $\mathfrak B$ serves as [basis of a topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)#Definition_and_basic_properties) then you can do that without knowing which topology.

You only have to check:

- Do the elements of $\mathfrak B$ cover $X$?
- If $B_1,B_2\in\mathfrak B$ and $x\in B_1\cap B_2$ then does there always exist some $B\in\mathfrak B$ with $x\in B\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$?

If and only if both questions get the answer "yes" then $\mathfrak B$ can be classified as basis of topology.

The topology will be the collection of unions of elements of $\mathfrak B$.

Comment: For the intersection, you may use the least common multiple of $b$ and $d$

Comment: Finding an element $B$ with $x\in B\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$ is according to the hint you received the same as finding an element $B$ with $x\in B\subseteq (x+b\mathbb Z)\cap (x+c\mathbb Z)$. As @GEdgar says: for that you can take $B=x+e\mathbb Z$ where $e$ is the least common multiple of $b$ and $d$.

Comment: Thanks! Furthermore I need to show that every set in $\mathfrak B$ is open and closed and decide whether the topology is Hausdorff. My idea is that every $\{a+ b \mathbb{Z} \}$ is open because the complement $\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{a+ b \mathbb{Z} \}$ is closed.And because $\overline{\{a+ b \mathbb{Z} \}}=\{a+ b \mathbb{Z} \}$ it is also closed

Comment: You stated without proof that $\overline{\{a+ b \mathbb{Z} \}}=\{a+ b \mathbb{Z} \}$.

Comment: If $\mathfrak B$ is a basis of a topology then this topology is completely determined by $\mathfrak B$. This in such a way that all elements of $\mathfrak B$ belong to that topology, hence are open. In order to prove that elements of $\mathfrak B$ are also closed you must prove that their complements are open in that topology, which is the case if these complements can be written as union of elements of $\mathfrak B$. Btw, you are not working with sets $\{a+b\mathbb Z\}$ here, but with sets $a+b\mathbb Z$.